# How do I fix "IntelliSense: PCH warning:"

Tags: visual-studio-2013, c++-cli, intellisense

On the first line of each file .cpp in a C++-cli project:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
```

..I have the following warning and intellisense refuses to work:

```
IntelliSense: PCH warning:
```

I've tried:

- Rebooting my machine.
- Deleting all the .sdf files.
- Doing a clean / rebuild all.

...what might cause this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but removing and re-adding the last pair of files I added to the project appears to have resolved the issue.

This is possibly because I renamed a class after adding it and the old versions got cached or something like that? Strange that clearing the .sdf file didn't fix it though.